# How to call a method from another class on buttonclick of Android activity?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have 2 classes in my project. 
1) activity_main and 
2) newclass

activity_main class has a button - button1. On click of this, I want to call a method from newclass; which is show() method.

So, I wrote: (in activity_main where I have defined button)

```
public void onClick(View v){

newclass.show();
}
```

This is giving an error in activity_main; saying newclass.show() is not static. If I make it static, it gives an error in newclass saying it shouldn't be static.

I might have to first create an object of newclass but m New to Java and New to Android too.

Can anyone please help me? Kindly let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Is method is static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> saying newclass.show() is not static. If I make it static, it gives an
>   error in newclass saying it shouldn't be static.

Means show() is not static method in `newclass` class(static method directly accessed using class name), you need to create class object to access method from.

```
newclass object=new newclass();
object.show();
```

Also read about [Java Naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: Thank you.. I think it should be object.show(): in second line. I did that and project didn't show any error. However, when trying to run in emulator, the app crashes on button click. (button 1). I have used .this in newclass() so, can't make it static. Any idea on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes.. I did change to object.show() in the first place. But on click of button, the app crashes.

Comment: @Android_Noob post your logcat. What is your newclass instance?

Comment: Thanks @ All... I figured it out. Just had to initialize the object of the class as ρяσѕρєя K said.!